# Command "jupyter-book" not found on Windows 10

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to build an HTML-page of my Jupyter notebook. I tried to run `jupyter-book build mybookname` but the command can't be found.

I tried to also install jupyter-book using the command `pip install jupyter-book` and added jupyter-book file path to environment variables, but I still can't build my book.

What should I do?

Answer (score -1):

MY jupyter notebook didn't work after installing and calling in CMD.

then i only use "pip install simplejson" in command prompt (cmd) . Then i write "jupyter notebook" and it work!

someone uses "pip uninstall simplejson" before "pip install simplejson".

Maybe python needs to reinstall something (pip install/unistall).